# Make child object go along the same curve as parent

Tags: modifiers

How can you make a child object automatically go along the same curve as the parent object?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possibility is to parent the cylinder to vertices of the curved object:

[image]

Before adding the curve modifier:

- in edit mode select 3 vertices of the object
- come back to object mode,
- select the cylinder
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the object
- then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and choose *"Vertex triangle"*

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Now the 'donut' moves with the large pole but it doesn't stay at the right place as your example.

Comment: Are the hook vertices you've used just the one inside/below the torus?

Comment: For some reason it didn't work because of the object already had a curve modifier. When I deleted the modifier and did parent the vertices it started working. Thanks for your help!